# How to autowire a bean which expects a method reference as one of its dependencies

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I have a class CustomMap as below:

```
@Component
public class CustomMap<T extends Map<String, Object>> {
  private final Supplier<T> mapType;

    /**
     * @param mapType Lambda for creating new instances of map type
     */
    public CustomMap(Supplier<T> mapType) {
       this.mapType = mapType;
    }
}
```

I have another class which is dependent on CustomMap class above:

```
@Component
public class A {
   private final CustomMap<MySupplier> customMap;

  public A(CustomMap<MySupplier> customMap) {
   this.customMap = customMap;
}
}

public class MySupplier extends HashMap<String, Object> {
    public MySupplier() {
    }
}
```

I have to somehow autowire both of these classes together so that spring takes care of initialization. I have to manually initialize class A as below which I want spring to take care.

```
A a = new A(new CustomMap<> (MySupplier::new))
```

Comment: Why? The fact that you use Spring doesn't mean you have to autowire _everything_.

Comment: There are lot of other classes which use A and I have to initialize those also manually as I am initializing A manually. It is lot of extra code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest creating a bean for `A` in the `ApplicationConfig`. E.g:

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig {
    @Bean
    public A a() {
        return new A(new CustomMap<> (MySupplier::new));
    }
}
```

You are probably using a component scan so you should get rid of the `@Component` annotations as the bean is now created in the `ApplicationConfig`.